# Autohotkey make me a new text file, but needs confirmation to make it

Tags: autohotkey

I use Autohotkey to make an new .txt file by this code:

```
; shift alt ctrl n
+!^n::
run, notepad.exe "C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Dropbox\priv\nota\%A_YYYY%-%A_MM%-%A_DD%--%A_Hour%-%A_Min%-%A_Sec%.txt"
sleep, 800
return
```

The new file will be named with a date-time string, and stored in my folder \nota\ . However, it will not produce the file directly, but instead opens the following dialog box [image]

asking for permission to do so. When answering "yes" the file is produced and stored correctly.

How do I modify my script to produce the file directly, without the need for the dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
; shift alt ctrl n
+!^n::
    FileAppend,, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Dropbox\priv\nota\%A_YYYY%-%A_MM%-%A_DD%--%A_Hour%-%A_Min%-%A_Sec%.txt
    Run C:\Users\%A_UserName%\Dropbox\priv\nota\%A_YYYY%-%A_MM%-%A_DD%--%A_Hour%-%A_Min%-%A_Sec%.txt
return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm